# custom filtering of methods in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, code-documentation

I would like to add to my sphinx documentation a menu, "todo items", which should contain all the methods of my project containing some todo items, like this:

""":todo: Fonction à implémenter"""

I would like to display the name of the class, the name of the concerned method(s), the number of the line and its content.

I found something that could be relevant : http://www.pythondoc.com/sphinx/ext/autodoc.html#skipping-members, but it only filter methods, and does not seem to be linked to the required informations(line numbers and line contents).

Is there a way to achieve this? Do you know some useful links?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sphinx extension [`sphinx.ext.todo`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/todo.html#module-sphinx.ext.todo).

Add it to your list of extensions and set `todo_include_todos` to `True` in your `conf.py`.

Then use the appropriate syntax for the todo directive in your docstrings, being careful to use proper indentation and whitespace.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, but it does not exactly solve my problem. Indeed, I would like sphinx to scan all my classes and to find all times I wrote #todo some_thing_to_do or something similar. What you proposed was to do is to write commentaries in RST file(If I well understood). any suggestion? Does it can be done?

Comment: reStructuredText does not read inline comments, so `#todo some_thing_to_do` will not work. You must use its syntax as documented in the link provided to the `sphinx.ext.todo` extension.